# Isolating shape from a non-pickable outline

Tags: qgis, shapefile

Zurich 3.18
British OS provide a shapefile for the civic boundaries. This layer is non-pickable and has no attribute table.
[image]
I need to use this outline to pick and create polylines within it. Is it possible to extract this enclosing shape?
Or, as I will have to repeatedly zoom in and out to trace over this outline, is it possible to Save the position and scale of this view so I can switch in and out?

Comment: which file are you using? with the exception of the high water mark all of the files in boundary-line are polygons and should be selectable.

Comment: What is "pickable"?

Comment: the yellow lines are not polygons and are not pickable. You can see the select item is greyed out. that is how it came in as a mbtiles_gb. With layer highlighted Edit select is all greyed out. Have I ADDed it incorrectly?

Comment: The bd_lines layer you are trying to "pick" from is not a ShapeFile. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/shapefiles/what-is-a-shapefile.htm

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot shows that the layer where you want to "pick" (select?) features is a vector tile layer: thus a remote data provider. In this case, you can't select any features. Vector tiles are mainly here for basemaps. You would need a [WFS connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Feature_Service) for remote access to vector data that you can use for proper processing.

> Vector tiles are rather specific vector data targeted to visualization
> and thus not comparable to generic geospatial (vector) data formats.

Citation: https://giswiki.hsr.ch/Vector_Tiles

Comment: Oh I see. I'll backtrack and see if I can get it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

WFS is not necessary, just a matter of selecting the right download file type. For the OS Boundaries download GML3. In QGIS use data source manager, select Geopackage, Connect then select the Boundaries of interest and Add (for the whole of the UK!). Easy when you know what todo!

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the data in a vector format that can be used by QGIS.

From the download:

https://osdatahub.os.uk/downloads/open/BoundaryLine

Select either "ESRI Shapefile" or "Geopackage" either will work for selecting.